# Trouble With Functions Program

Tags: visual-c++

I'm having trouble with my rock paper scissors game code and cannot seem to narrow down what it really is. I believe there are issues with the displayResults function and the getComputerchoice function. Sorry I'm very new to this class and not looking for anyone to write the code for me but I would appreciate any pointers towards the right direction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int getComputerChoice ();
int getUserChoice ();
int determineWinner (int userchoice, int compchoice);
void displayResults (int &userchoice, int &compchoice, int &wincode);
string convertchoice (int userchoice, int compchoice);
string convertwin (int wincode);



int main ()
{
    int compchoice, userchoice, wincode;
    string compname, username, winname;

    cout << "Game Menu" << endl;
    cout << "---------" << endl;
    cout << "1) Rock" << endl;
    cout << "2) Paper" << endl;
    cout << "3) Scissors" << endl;
    cout << "4) Quit" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    userchoice = getUserChoice ();
    compchoice = getComputerChoice ();
    while (userchoice != 4)
    {   
        wincode = determineWinner (userchoice, compchoice);

        displayResults (userchoice, compchoice, wincode);

        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "=======================================" << endl;
        cout << "You selected: " << userchoice << endl;
        cout << "The computer selected: " << compchoice << endl;
        cout << "Game Winner: " << wincode << endl;
        cout << "=======================================" << endl;
        cout << "Game Menu" << endl;
        cout << "---------" << endl;
        cout << "1) Rock" << endl;
        cout << "2) Paper" << endl;
        cout << "3) Scissors" << endl;
        cout << "4) Quit" << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: " << endl;
        cin >> userchoice;
        compchoice = getComputerChoice ();
    }

    return 0;
}


int getUserChoice ()
{
    int userchoice;
    cout << "Enter your choice: " << endl;
    cin >> userchoice;
    return userchoice;

}

int getComputerChoice ()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    compchoice = rand() % 3 + 1;
    return compchoice;
}

int determineWinner (int userchoice, int compchoice)
{   if (compchoice == userchoice)
    {   return 0;
    }
    else if (compchoice == 1 && userchoice == 3)
    {   return 2;
    }
    else if (userchoice == 1 && compchoice == 3)
    {   return 1;
    }
    else if (compchoice == 3 && userchoice == 2)
    {   return 2;
    }
    else if (userchoice == 3 && compchoice == 2)
    {   return 1;
    }
    else if (compchoice == 2 && userchoice == 1)
    {   return 2;
    }
    else if (userchoice == 2 && compchoice == 1)
    {   return 1;
    }
}

void displayResults (int &userchoice, int &compchoice, int &wincode)
{
    username = string convertchoice (userchoice);
    compname = string convertchoice (compchoice);
    winname = string convertwin (wincode);
}

string convertchoice (int userchoice, int compchoice)
{
    int choice;
    userchoice = choice;
    compchoice = choice;
    if (choice == 1)
    {   return "Rock";
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {   return "Paper";
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {   return "Scissors";
    }
}

string convertwin (int wincode)
{
    if (wincode == 1)
    {
        return "User";
    }
    else if (wincode == 2)
    {
        return "Computer";
    }
    else if (wincode == 0)
    {
        return "Tie";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's okay to not know what the specific cause of a problem is in your code, but you should at least say what is wrong with the behaviour of your code.  What does "trouble" mean in this case?

Comment: a lot of undeclared identifier errors and identifier not found errors along with "function does not take 1 arguments" errors. That's all I'm able to really elaborate on I apologize.

Comment: That may have something to do with the fact that your code uses a lot of undeclared identifiers (such as `compchoice` in `getComputerChoice`, line 68; or `username` in `displayResults`, line 98). Then you have lines like `username = string convertchoice (userchoice);` which only remotely resemble C++ code; I'm hard-pressed to guess what you were trying to do there.